# how to increase the area of the link in css

Tags: css

i have set the property of link as follow

```
    .heading-text a
            {
               font-family: verdana;
               font-size:12px;
               color:#124253;
               width:100%;
               height:40px;
               text-align: center;
               cursor: pointer;   
            }
```

to make the height of the link as per it's parent div but it's not working

when  i have set following property

```
    .heading-text a
            {
                padding:11px 0px;  
            }
```

then it work properly is there any way in css by which i can increase the height of the area of the link without padding

Request to give answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 4):

add this to your css :

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 2):

`<a>` tags are inline by default. Change it to block:

```
.heading-text a
{
    display: block; /* Add this */
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#124253;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;   
}
```

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptSEs/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following to your css:

```
display: inline-block;
```

In difference to *"display: block;"*, this has inline too, means you can **define the size but the element is still inline** as before.

Comment: Good point about the element keeping its inline features, but it's important to remember support is flaky in IE<=7

Answer (score 0):

**Use any one or both of this-**

```
display: inline-block;
```

or

```
float:left; /*or right*/
```